# jquery datatable body rows unaligned with head rows

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

Hi i'm using jquery datatables and whenver i set table-sm class to make table smaller the rows are uneven from body with the head... I can't seem to find out why does this happen

[image]

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="tblParametros" class="table table-sm table-bordered border-dark table-striped table-light text-center" width="100%">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan="2">Id</th>
                            <th rowspan="2">Referência</th>
                            <th rowspan="2">UAP</th>
                            <th rowspan="2">Dias</th>
                            <th rowspan="2">Turnos</th>
                            <th colspan="4">PAB(s)</th>
                            <th rowspan="2"></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nº</th>
                            <th>Alcance de Abastecimento</th>
                            <th>Quantidade Mínima</th>
                            <th>Quantidade Máxima</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>

<script>
     $(function () {
        table = $('#tblParametros').DataTable({
            scrollY: "60vh",
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("List","Parametros")',
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "id" },
                { data: "referencia" },
                { data: "uap" },
                { data: "numDias" },
                { data: "numTurnos" },
                { data: "numPAB" },
                { data: "alcanceAbastecimento" },
                { data: "qtdMin" },
                { data: "qtdMax" },
                {
                    data: "id",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {

                        return '<button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="EditParametro('+data+')" data-izimodal-open="#modal" data-izimodal-transitionin="fadeInDown">' +
                            '<i class="fas fa-edit"></i>' +
                            '</button>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way to make the table rows smaller without creating a bunch of CSS selectors? I would appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I can't decide what the goal is.
if we want to make table rows narrower then we can target the containing div:

```
.table-responsive{
   width: 50%;
 }
```

if we want to make the text of the row smaller then:

```
.table-responsive{
   font-size: 50%;
 }
```

i am happy to elaborate.

Comment: well anything similar to what table-sm does which is reduce the rows height size